# About community wiki or protected questions used only for reference (usually breaking some site rules)

Tags: discussion

I usually see questions at other SEs that are not under the site rules, like questions (off-topic or not) that result in answers with lists, discussions, etc. that are protected or turned community wiki and used only for referential purposes, but should not be used as examples of allowed questions.

My questions are:

1. When can we ask those types of reference questions?
2. Are there rules to what referential question could be asked?

Comment: +1 for bringing this up. When you ask "when can we ask...", we haven't really discussed "when should we ask...", especially for "reference requests" so I posted this as a separate discussion [here](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/178/should-we-allow-reference-questions-on-main). There are other types of questions, which should be discussed here (e.g. list questions like "what are all the irregular verbs?").

Answer (score 7):

That’s a very good question.

There are several different models we could follow, but I imagine that in the long run, we will move to having reference-type questions here on meta, not on main. This seems to be the direction that other language sites are taking, although I’ve only looked at a couple of them so far.

For example, Flimzy’s question about the existence of a Portuguese dictionary with IPA pronunciations probably should be migrated here to our meta.  I reopened it without thinking things through well enough, mostly because we had not yet had the discussion that you have yourself just been kind enough to raise for us.

What I am uncertain of is whether that sort of information should be under one rather generic “resources” question, or whether there should instead be one question for dictionaries, another for something else, et cetera.

As these questions become better developed and settled in, we can also have links to them from [our Help Center](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help), which has yet to be (much) customized for our site.

Comment: +1 I agree with you